# API does not hit the controller in production mode

Tags: .net, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0, clean-architecture, asp.net-core-6.0

I follow the clean architecture project in .net 6.0

this is ApiControllerBase

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public abstract class ApiControllerBase : ControllerBase
{
    private ISender _mediator = null!;

    protected ISender Mediator => _mediator ??= HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ISender>();
}
```

In my todo Controller, I had the following endpoint

```
[Route("api/public/todo")]

[AllowAnonymous]

public class PublicTodoController : ApiControllerBase
{
   [HttpGet("all")]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]

public async Task<IActionResult> All()
{
    var result = await Mediator.Send(new GetAllTodoQuery());

    return Ok(result);
}
    
}
```

when I run production locally it runs but
when I sent the request to the above endpoint it throw the following information

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/api/public/todo/all - -
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[0]
      Executing endpoint 'TT.WebApi.Controllers.Public.PublicTodoController.All (TT.WebApi)'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker[3]
      Route matched with {action = "All", controller = "PublicTodoController"}. Executing controller action with signature System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult] All() on controller TT.WebApi.Controllers.Public.PublicTodoController (TT.WebApi).
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ObjectResultExecutor[1]
      Executing ObjectResult, writing value of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ProblemDetails'.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
      Executed action TT.WebApi.Controllers.Public.PublicTodoController.All (TT.WebApi) in 104.4992ms
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[1]
      Executed endpoint 'TT.WebApi.Controllers.Public.PublicTodoController.All (TT.WebApi)'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/api/public/todo/all - - - 500 132 application/problem+json;+charset=utf-8 194.1319ms
```

Comment: Have you identified **what** it is that is `null`? My guess is `this.appSettings.Secret` or `this.appSettings`

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen   values are not null

Comment: So, have you identified what it is that is null?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen unable to find
development environment  api work

Comment: @AbdulganyMohamed please check if all the values in appsettings.Development.json is in appsettings.json

Comment: @HishamHafeel yes it has